# Why does Hayley decide to stay?

Tags: the-originals

In *The Originals* s5e06 Hayles undergoes binding and becomes a vampire, not a hybrid, therefore she is no longer able to survive daylight. On the other hand, there's Roman who has a daylight ring, so **why does Hayley stay instead of just taking Roman's ring and leaving with Hope?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly the only answer I can think of is plot device sadly. I had the same thought the other day when I watched it for the first time (just finished the series!)